# MySQL How can UPDATE deal with duplicated primary keys?

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table with a combined primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE doc (doc_num INTEGER,
                  doc_date DATE,
                  doc_line INTEGER,
                  line_text VARCHAR(10),
                  PRIMARY KEY (doc_num,doc_date,doc_line));
```

Sometimes it is necessary to set all dates to a single one like so:

```
UPDATE doc
SET (doc_date=CURDATE());
```

However, doing this could potentially cause a duplicated primary key as doc_line
would need to be renumbered.

If I were to try and set doc_line to a new value with a subquery (for instance
count(doc_line)+1) I'd run into error 1093 because I'd be selecting the same
table I´m updating.

When inserting it is possible to use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY to deal with
this issue, but the same isn't possible when doing an UPDATE.

How can I properly renumerate doc_line?

Comment: Surely the doc_num and doc_line are the unique bits of the key and date is information or is it the case that you are maintaining a change log in the same table based on date for doc_num and doc_line?

Comment: No, all three are unique bits of the key. To further elaborate on this: It is possible for a doc_num 1 to have lines 1,2,3 on 2022-08-18, and then also 
doc_num 1 have two more lines on 2022-08-19, in this case the lines would have
to be renumbered 4 and 5.

Comment: *doc_line would need to be renumbered.* I.e. the operation becomes iterative. So you must: #1 - define renumbering algorithm; #2 - specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: A worked example would help. As is I cannot see why lines would need to be renumbered on an update , I get that when you INSERT 2 more lines you would have to increment line nos to 4 and 5 but an UPDATE to  the date does not imply this is necessary nor can an update add rows and given the line nos are unique cannot cause a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution I tested on MySQL 8.0.29:

```
CREATE TABLE doc (doc_num INTEGER,
                  doc_date DATE,
                  doc_line INTEGER,
                  line_text VARCHAR(10),
                  PRIMARY KEY (doc_num,doc_date,doc_line));

INSERT INTO doc VALUES
(1, '2022-08-18', 1, 'line'),
(1, '2022-08-18', 2, 'line'),
(1, '2022-08-18', 3, 'line'),
(1, '2022-08-19', 1, 'line');

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT doc_num, doc_date, doc_line,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doc_num ORDER BY doc_date, doc_line) AS rownum
  FROM doc
)
UPDATE doc JOIN cte USING (doc_num, doc_date, doc_line)
SET doc.doc_line = cte.rownum;

UPDATE doc SET doc_date = CURDATE();
```

It must be done as two separate UPDATEs to avoid the duplicate key violation. I tried a test where I set `doc_date = CURDATE()` in the first UPDATE, but the first row updated conflicted because I was setting the date to 2022-08-19, and that conflicted with the fourth row.

Comment: Thank you, this was very educative, it's my first time learning about common table expressions. They are a great reason to upgrade from 5.7.